# Предлог к или ко: "проценты причислить ко вкладу" или "к вкладу"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать:
 проценты причислить ко вкладу или к вкладу?

Answer (score 1):

Проценты ***на***числяются **на вклад**. 
Или *проценты **по** вкладу*: *"жить на проценты по вкладу"*
А вот если надо подчеркнуть, что проценты поступают на тот же вклад (как это обычно происходит со вкладами физических лиц), а не на отдельный счет, про говорят, что *проценты по вкладу (на вклад) **прибавляются** к основному счету (т.н. "телу депозита")*.

Answer (score 1):

По фонетическим причинам (во избежание 4 согласных подряд и 3 подряд глухих) "причислять" лучше "**ко** вкладам", хотя и предлог "к" не будет ошибкой. Что касается общедоступных писаных правил, они обычно ограничиваются перечислением устойчивых словесных сочетаний, одна группа которых допускает только один вариант, другая - оба. У Розенталя упоминается только частный случай употребления предлога "ко" на чисто *фонетических* основаниях (односложные слова).

Answer (score 0):

Можно и "причислить к вкладу". Это старая норма. А в профессиональной речи осталось как основная.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/134635/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C
Если говорить "причислить проценты к вкладу", то для "ко" здесь нет причин. 
А если просто "причисль к(о) вкладу", но по фонетическим причанам лучше с "ко".